# bracey-vim cannot detect previous directory( ../ ) please help

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-networks, python, mean

When I try to link a file or image from a previous directory cannot load it in the browser says the error.

this is my directory

```
webdev/
.        html/
.            index.html
.        css/
.             para.html
```

When I link para.html in index.html through it doesn't work in bracey while it works in live-server and reloads also

```
href="../css/para.html"  :
```

says

> webdev/html/css/para.html no such file or directory

Please help.
Thank you so much.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about vim have a specific outlet: https://vi.stackexchange.com